# Titles of additional websites don't show correctly (they show the URL of the default store/website)

Tags: page-title, title

```
Magento 1.9.3.7 
Porto theme
```

I've setup a default store and then a few additional websites/stores. They all have their own domains. I customized the look and content of each domain/website within the single Magento installation and everything shows up the way it suppose to including a different favicon for each domain/website BUT the title of all the other stores shows the URL of the main/default website/store. It actually flicks for a moment when loading - first it shows the URL of the domain/store it is loading (which is weird in itself because I didn't enter the entire URL in the www.MYadditionalSITE.com format into

```
System > Configuration > General > Design > HTML Head > Default Title
```

**but only the words MYadditionalSITE**).

After it flicks the URL of the actual site - it then displays the URL of the default domain/website in the browser's tab in the following format:

DEFAULTstore.com

If I save the website onto the bar - I see the **correct favicon** *and next to it:*

**DEFAULTstore.com**

When I place my mouse over that - I see:

```
DEFAULTstore.com
and underneath it:
www.MYadditionalSITE.com
```

***I deleted all Cache (it's currently disabled anyways) and re-indexed everything.***

Answer (score 0):

*I just figured it out!*

I had a reference to a specific CMS page in

```
System - Configuration - General - Web - Default Pages - CMS Home Page
```

This CMS page had "**DEFAULTstore.com**" **in the Page Title** *

*The solution is to create a new CMS page just for that domain/website/store and put MYadditionalSITE in the Page Title there.*